# Can not write to QTcpSocket inside QRunnable

Tags: qt, qthread, qtconcurrent

I built a server in `Qt` that takes every client that connects to it and sends the connection away to worker thread (I implement this with `QRunnable` and I connect the thread to `QThreadPool`).

In my thread I read without a problem from the socket (`QTcpSocket socket` ) but when I try to write to it I get the following error:

> QObject: Can not create children for a parent that is in a different
>   thread. The parent thread is QThread (0x28602f90860)

I tried to fix this by adding the code line:

`socket->setParent(this);`

In the constructor of my thread - but it did not help, I got the following error:

> QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
>   (Parent is QNativeSocketEngine(0x1dab6331c60), parent's thread
>   is QThread(0x1dab62eacf0), current thread is QThread(0x1dab632b140)
>   QSocketNotifier: Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from
>   another thread

Does anyone know what this problem is or how to solve it?

A sparse example of the relevant code snippets:

```
class myTask  : public QObject , public QRunnable, public parser
{
     Q_OBJECT

public:
    myTask(QTcpSocket *s)
    {
        socket = s;
        socket->setParent(this);
        // if i do here socket->write("hello world"); it's work , but not in run()
    }

signals:
    void Result(int num);

protected:
    void run()
    {
        socket->write("hello world"); // i get here the error
    }

private:
    QTcpSocket *socket;
};


/* the creation of the worknig thread and the tcp client creation */
void MyClient::readyRead()
{

     myTask * mtask = new myTask(socket);
     mtask->setAutoDelete(true);

     // connect result to our loacal result function
     connect(mtask, SIGNAL(Result(int)), this, SLOT(taskResults(int)), Qt::QueuedConnection);

     //start havy job
     QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(mtask);
}

void MyClient::SetSocket(int descriptor)
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(connected()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));


    socket->setSocketDescriptor(descriptor);
    qDebug() <<"[*] client connected";

}

class MyClient : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyClient(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void SetSocket(int descriptor);

signals:


public slots:
    void connected();
    void disconnected();
    void readyRead();
    void taskResults(int num);

private:
    QTcpSocket *socket;
};
```

Comment: Of course the problem has likely to do with something else and not QRunnable which is just about spawning non-blocking task. Of course you can work with QTcpSocket in non-blocking manner without the "task". I would start with that and stripping of example of unnecessary details usually helps. And if that works then the problem is with *the way QRunnable used* and *not* with the socket.

Comment: if u try to send from `myTak constructor` it's works fine , only from the minit i get into `run()` i start to get errors

Comment: What is the "heavy job"? As @AlexanderVX, Qt's network module is asynchronous and designed to be used in the main thread, so you shouldn't need to move any of the network I/O itself to another thread. Also, you can't move objects to a thread in which their parent does not live, nor should you be calling the socket's `read()` or `write()` functions from a thread in which the socket doesn't live.

Comment: `heavy job` is take from the network files make some monipulation on this and write them back to the client , i do it in a seperate runable because i want a real multy threading and avoid ANY blocking acticity - it's supposed to be fully functional real server.

Comment: @YOKO I suggest you start by reading Qt documentation about threads and QObject. This will help you to understand what you can and cannot do when playing with QObject accross threads: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html

Comment: @YOKO, you already have a solution as you said ... _"send from myTask constructor it's works fine"_. So class `myTask` owns run()  and thats the thread socket goes with ..  try to make `MyClient` class inherit `myTask`  so that you don't create explicit myTask object ..

Comment: I eventually fix this issues with `emit` and signals at  `my_task` to `MyClient` for writing, ready read and ready write , i think this a clever way to combine asinc actions with multythreading (but if i rung i will be happy if someone currect me)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `QTcpServer` documentation one of the notes says:

> **Note:** If you want to handle an incoming connection as a new `QTcpSocket` object in another thread you have to pass the `socketDescriptor` to the other thread and create the `QTcpSocket` object there and use its `setSocketDescriptor()` method.

To do that there's also a note on `incomingConnection()`:

> **Note:** The returned `QTcpSocket` object cannot be used from another thread. If you want to use an incoming connection from another thread, you need to **override** `incomingConnection()`.

So subclass `QTcpServer` class and implement an `incomingConnection()` that gets the **socket descriptor** and send to the thread.

Here an [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-threadedfortuneserver-example.html) of a threaded `QTcpServer`.